# api/authenticate getting 404 error in microservice jhipster

Tags: api, authentication, http-status-code-404, jhipster

API:= http://localhost:8081/api/authenticate
Body:= {"password":"abc","username":"abc"}
response:=
{
"timestamp": "2021-10-22T12:18:36.440+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"path": "/api/authenticate"
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKCIQ.png)

Comment: You haven't given enough information to understand your problem. Put your code and give details of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say which version of JHipster nor which authentication type you selected but your title states "microservice" so I guess it should be JWT or OAuth2.

So it's normal that you can't authenticate with a username/password because your microservice expect a token which should have been provided by a JHipster gateway application.